# DRYing out the path.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, dry

I'm new to cucumber, and I'd like to ask how to dry out this code (which does not contain errors):

```
when /^the user page$/
  users_path

when /^the review page$/
  reviews_path
```

I tried to use regexp like

```
when /^the (.+) page$/
  $1.to_s+'s_path'
```

but apparently it is wrong. Thanks in advance!

**Solution (based on answer by [aledalgrande](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419656/aledalgrande)):**

```
when /^the (.+) page$/ 
 send("#{$1}s_path")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
When /^the "(.+)" page$/ do |destination|
  send("#{destination}s_path")
end
```

Comment: it looks better, but unfortunately does not work. Thanks for suggesting "send".

Comment: in this version it gives a syntactic error. When I inserted **do** before **|destination|**, I got `syntax error, unexpected keyword_do, expecting keyword_then or ',' or ';' or '\n' when /^the (.+) page$/ do |destination|`. Then I replaced **do** by **then** and got `syntax error, unexpected '|'`.
Playing further with your code, I made it work by changing as follows 
`when /^the (.+) page$/ 
send("#{$1}s_path")` 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Changed to include the omitted `do` and also quotes. It's strange it's not working for you with that syntax.

Comment: can't argue about which solution is 'shorter' but personally I think that this one is more of a hack then DRY. Imagine having a typo in your test **"When the revievs path"**. How long is going to take you, in a month from now, to locate it?? Seconds with **"Can't find mapping from revievs to a path."**?? Try to convert it to cost.

Comment: You are right, but thinking it this way, I'd have no need to change my code that I started with. Am I right?

Comment: I agree with you Kocur4d, but the focus here wasn't on functionality of the code of the step.

Answer (score 1):

You can add:

features/support/paths.rb

```
module PathHelpers
  def path_to(page_name)
    case page_name
    when /user/i
      users_path
    when /review/i
      reviews_path
    when /home/i
      root_path
    #add custom here
    else
      raise "Can't find mapping from \"#{page_name}\" to a path."
    end
  end
end

World(PathHelpers)
```

and call it:

```
when /^the (.+) page$/ do |page|
  visit path_to(page)
end
```

Comment: you define a helper and have one place where you need to change behaviour, adding new paths, without looking anywhere else in a code. I think its DRY. DRY don't say write less lines of code but write a code you can modify easily and in one place. I update answer with a call to word, haven't been using cucumber for a while but it might be needed.

Comment: thanks! I hope your version works, though the solution that I've just added seems to be more concise. Thank you for your suggestions!